# JavaScript function only running once on remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a two buttons, one to create, one to remove different uses

```
<button id="create-user" class="btn btn-primary" style='float:right; margin-right: 230px;'>Add</button>
```

The above button creates and is just in a div. Nothing special.
The remove button however is made dynamically in the table below..
The function lookup is calling a rest application with 3 different types of id in the url that is searches. The table populates and the data is correct.

```
<table id="users" class="table" align="center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>=ID</th>=
            <th>JSON Value</th>
            <th>placeholder for remove</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
                // lookup function to call rest API and existing gather data
                $json = lookup($name, $id[$i], "GET");
                if ($json["Value"] == "Y" || $json["Value"] == "N"){
                    $temp = $json["Value"];
                    echo "<tr id='$name'><td>$name</td><td>$id</td><td>$temp</td><td><button id='remove-user' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'>Remove</button></td></tr>";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My issue is that when I click remove, it removes it successfully (testing with just rowid = 1 for now. But when I add, it add into the table and the list of id's that I search, it doesnt want to remove it again. Only works one time every page refresh. The add works constantly where the remove does not.

```
 <script>

    $( function() {
        var dialog, form,
        name = $( "#name" ),
        id = $( "#id" ),
        id_val = $( "#id_val" ),
        allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( id ).add( id_val );
        var current_IDS = getIDS();

        function getIDS(){
            // go through table and gather existing keys
            var table = document.getElementById("users");
            var IDS = [];
            var first_row = table.rows[1];
            var second_row = table.rows[2];
            var third_row = table.rows[3];
            if(typeof first_row.id !== 'undefined'){
                IDS.push(first_row.id);
            }
            if(typeof second_row !== 'undefined'){
                IDS.push(second_row.id);
            }
            if(typeof third_row !== 'undefined'){
                IDS.push(third_row.id);
            }
            return IDS;
        }

        // compare keys to make sure not adding duplicates
        function checkIDS(id){
            if(current_IDS[0] == id){
                return false;
            } else if(current_IDS[1] == id){
                return false;
            } else if(current_IDS[2] == id){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        }

        function addUser() {
            //make sure not duplicate
            var valid = checkIDS(id_val.val());
            if(valid) {
                current_IDS.push(id_val.val());
                $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr id="+name.val()+">" +
                "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + id.val() + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + id_val.val() + "</td>" +
                "<button id='remove-user' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'>Remove</button></td>" +
                "</tr>" );
                dialog.dialog( "close" );
                // post and send to restapi.php rest call
                $.post("restapi.php", {
                    name: name.val(),
                    id: id.val(),
                    id_val: id_val.val()
                });
            } else{
                alert("id already exists!");
            }
            return valid;
        }

        function deleteRow(rowid){
            var rows = getIDS();
            var first_row = rows[0];
            var second_row = rows[1];
            var third_row = rows[2];
            // check row id to see if its in table
            if(rowid == first_row || rowid == second_row || rowid == third_row ) {
                var row = document.getElementById(rowid);
                row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
                // remove from list of current ids
                current_IDS.splice(current_IDS.indexOf(rowid), 1);
            }
        }
        dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 400,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Create new id": addUser,
                Cancel: function() {
                    dialog.dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close: function() {
                form[ 0 ].reset();
                allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
            }
        });

        form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            addUser();
        });

        $( "#create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
            dialog.dialog( "open" );
        });

        $("#remove-user").button().on( "click", function() {
            deleteRow("testname"); //specifically target testname to see if i can keep adding/removing
        });
    });
</script>
```

My question is how do I make my remove work consistently without having to refresh the page constantly.

Comment: Try changing `$("#remove-user").button()` to `$('table#users').on("click", "#remove-user", function()...`

Comment: @dunc this worked! Would you be willing to expand on the reason behind this?

Comment: Looks like someone else has beaten me to it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [event-deligation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

So change

```
$("#remove-user").button()
```

to

```
$('table#users').on("click", "#remove-user", function()...
```

Note: In a simple way to say `jquery` doesn't recognize dynamically added content by-default.So to address those element to perform some action,we try to use parent elements those are already present at the time of `document` load/render.

***Important:*** Multiple same `id` is very bad coding practice, so change `id="remove-user"` to `class="remove-user"` on each delete button and then modify code like below:-

```
$('table#users').on("click", ".remove-user", function()...
```

`class` meant to represent a group of elements while `id` meant to represent unique element while performing any kind of action through javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Thanks! Will this also work  with the rest calls when I implement that functionality to the delete function?

Comment: @Travis  hope so.